# Proving $d(f^*e_i')=0$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $f:M\to N$ be a differentiable map between two manifolds. $e_i$ is a basis vector of $N$ with respect to some chart and $e_i'$ its dual (i.e. $e_i'(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$). How do I prove the following?
$$d(f^*e_i')=0$$
By definition of $f^*$ we have
$$d(f^*e_i')=d(e_i'\circ df).$$
But how to proceed?

Edit: My definition of the differential $d$: Let $\omega$ be a differentiable $k$-form on $M$ (i.e. $\omega\in \Lambda^kM$) and $(b_i)_{1\le i \le n}$ the standard basis with respect to some chart $x$ and $(b_i')_{1\le i \le n}$ its dual basis. Then we have
$$d\omega = \sum_{|I|=k} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{\partial\omega_I}{\partial x_r}b_r'\wedge b_I'$$
in the domain of $x$. In our special case above $f$ is a 0-form and $f^*e_i'$ is a 1-form.

Comment: $df$ is equals to $f_*$, right?

Comment: I don't know how $f_*$ is defined but I edited my question that you have the definition I use.

Comment: Is your conclusion right without restriction on $f$ or the basis?

Comment: usually a 0-form in $M$ is a map $M\to\Bbb{R}$... [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Concept ] **and** if $f:M\to N$ is a smooth map then its differential is a linear map between the tangent spaces $f_*:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$

Comment: Yeah, that's just a special case of my definition.

Comment: how does it fit your definition of 0-form  on $\Lambda^0M$?

Comment: You're totally right. With $df$ I just mean your map $f_*$ and it is not a special case of my definition. It only would be a special case if $N$ were the reals. Because then you can identify an element of the tangent space with a real number.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain  We choose an equivalent notations: put $e_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ then $e^{i}=dx_{i}$. Note that $f^{*}\circ d= d\circ f^{*}$ and $d\circ d=0$ So $d(f^{*}(e^{i}))=f^{*}(d(dx_{i}))=0$.

Comment: It is well known that the pull-back conmutes with the exterior derivative, that is $d \circ f^* = f^*\circ d $ and also the cocicle condition states $d \circ d=0$.